# How to change the font of fourteen thousand Word files with Python OR other languages؟

Tags: python, fonts, ms-word

I have a project where I need to change the font of 14,000 Word files. I want to do this with Python and change the font of all 14,000 files at once without damaging anything.

It's okay if it's not with Python, it's okay with other languages too

Comment: Looks like you're asking someone to write this for you. If so, you're in the wrong place as stack**overflow** is not a coding service

Comment: No, it's not like that. I wrote the codes for importing Word files, but I don't know how to change the font. I don't know if it's possible or not. I just wanted to see if there is a home book for it or a guide to do it better.

Comment: There are numerous Python modules available for processing Microsoft Word documents. Their capabilities differ. You'll need to find one that supports font modification

Comment: thanksDo you have an option?